# ReactJS - What is difference between component state and class variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I think it works differently but I don't know how it works.

## 1. Using class variable

```
export default class Test extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.active = false;
  }

  render() {
    this.active = this.props.name === 'Dan'? true : false;
    return (
      <div>
        {this.active? 'ssup?' : 'noooo'}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

## 2. Using React component state

```
export default class Test extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = { active: false };
  }

  render() {
    if(this.props.name === 'Dan') {
      this.setState({active: true});
    }
    return (
      <div>
        {this.active? 'ssup?' : 'noooo'}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I think it doesn't need to re-render using State if it's only affected by received props.

Comment: The above codes are a sample. 'active' needs to run other logic also.

Comment: The output of a component usually depends on the props passed in and *optionally* on its own internal state. If the state is changed via `setState`, the component is scheduled to rerender. Note that you cannot actually call `setState` inside `render`, due to that fact. Class variables are mainly useful for storing side-effect data, such as a subscription ID, so that the subscription can be cancelled when the component unmounts. Your examples neither warrants class variables nor state.

Comment: Your examples don't make sense. Why have state at all? Your component is a pure function of the `name` property.

Comment: Please just focus on the difference. Sorry to my bad sample :(

Comment: Does any of the answers below help you find the difference ?

Answer (score 24):

The difference between the two is that React will re-render your component when state changes (with `this.setState(/*...*/)`).

If you update the class variable, React will be unaware of it and won't re-render your component.

Note that what you're achieving in your code requires neither state or class variable. You're simply computing another value directly from the props. A better way to write your component would be like this :

```
export default class Test extends Component {
  render() {
    const active = this.props.name === 'Dan';
    return (
      <div>
        {active? 'ssup?' : 'noooo'}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The simple answer to your question is that by using `state` you call the `setState()` which automatically calls `render()` automatically. Which cannot be obtained by `class variables`

You use the `state variables` when you want to change the component when that variable is changed.

When you don't want to automatically call `render()` you use the `class` variables

Answer (score 2):

**React component only re-renders when there are changes to `state` or `class`. But updating class variable involves neither so it does not trigger render.**

Though using `state` may seem similar to class variable but `state` is a protected keyword in React that refers to stored component data. The major difference between using class variables and state is updating data. Instead of manually reassigning the variable, you call `this.setState()`.

When you call `this.setState()`. It compares this new state to the previous state. If there is a change, React re-renders the component, resulting in the updated count value displayed on the screen.

But when you update class variable, it sure gets updated but does no re-render. You can do so using  `this.forceUpdate()`. But Normally you should try to avoid all uses of `forceUpdate()` and only read from `this.props` and `this.state` in `render()`.

Refer to [this](https://www.seanmcp.com/articles/storing-data-in-state-vs-class-variable/) article for detailed info.